# Content changing in simulator vs real phone

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, constraints, uibezierpath

I have a widget with a height of 110. I am programmatically making a circle using the UIBezierPath. I have a view within the widget called ClockView (width and height of 80) which is centered on the x-axis, and it's center should also be the center of the circle. I was able to achieve this as you will see in the simulator screen shot, but when running on an actual device, it is completely off.

```
    let centerY = 15 + clockView.frame.size.height/2
    let centerX = 15 + clockView.frame.size.width/2
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)
```

Simulator screenshot
[image: Simulator screenshot]

iPhone screenshot
[image: iPhone screenshot]

Storyboard
[image: Storyboard]

Complete view setup code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(self.refresh) , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    circleRadius = CGFloat(2*(clockView.frame.size.height/2)/2.4)
    lineWidth = Double(circleRadius/5)
    //view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.95, green:0.97, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0)

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    let guide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
    let height = guide.layoutFrame.size.height

    let padding = (height - clockView.frame.size.width)/2
    print("PADDING = \(padding)")
    let centerY = 15 + clockView.frame.size.height/2
    let centerX = 15 + clockView.frame.size.width/2
    let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerX, y: centerY)

    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: circleRadius, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 3 * CGFloat.pi / 2, clockwise: true)

    trackLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.96, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(lineWidth)
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    trackLayer.shadowColor = UIColor(red:0.46, green:0.57, blue:0.68, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    trackLayer.shadowRadius = 13
    trackLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    trackLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
    view.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    completeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
    completeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0.50, green:0.73, blue:0.98, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    completeLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(lineWidth)
    completeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    completeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    completeLayer.strokeEnd = 0
    view.layer.addSublayer(completeLayer)

    let topCirclePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerPoint, radius: CGFloat(Double(circleRadius)-Double(lineWidth)), startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
    timeLayer.path = topCirclePath.cgPath
    timeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.96, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    timeLayer.lineWidth = CGFloat(lineWidth)
    timeLayer.fillColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.96, blue:1.00, alpha:1.0).cgColor
    timeLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
    timeLayer.shadowRadius = 10
    timeLayer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
    timeLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    timeLayer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
    view.layer.addSublayer(timeLayer)

    view.layer.insertSublayer(clockView.layer, above: timeLayer)
    refresh()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Comment: You're not showing enough code. Where is the code that you showed, in a larger context? Merely making a bezier path does not draw a circle, so where's the circle drawing code?

Comment: I will add it right now

Answer (score 0):

First step would be double checking that your phone and simulator are the same iOS and model.

Second thing for the post, probably post more of your code showing the exact items/elements in question. (Namely the label/item you have for your time, it might be missing some sort of item/tag/value that's needed on hardware.)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I added the code for the circle setup. The time label is not the problem as you can see in both cases it is matching up to the center with the labels on the right

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, I made the center coordinates equal to the width and height of the ClockView divided by 2. I also added the circles as part of the ClockView layer instead of the main layer.